# Is there any easy method for splitting text in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string, split, slice

Is there any easy method for splitting text in VB.NET? (using a start and end string to grab whats in between?)

I do this all the time in JScript with the following:

> ```
> <junk>
> <blah>
> <data>someData1</data>
> <data>someData2</data>
> <data>someData3</data>
> </blah>
> </junk>
> ```

```
var data = string.split('<data>')[1].split('</data>')[0];
```

would give me "someData1" by changing the [1] index to [2] would give me "someData2" very easy

for some reason this seems to be very difficult to achieve in VB.NET.

Here is a chunk of the actual HTML I'm dealing with:

```
<...malformed html>
<div style='font-size:10pt;font-family:Times;color:#000000;position:absolute;top:2731.068;left:48'>Total</div>
<div style='font-size:10pt;font-family:Times;color:#000000;position:absolute;top:2731.068;left:346.2141'>18,072.59</div>
<div style='font-size:10pt;font-family:Times;color:#000000;position:absolute;top:2731.068;left:444.3433'>100.00%</div>
<div style='font-size:10pt;font-family:Times;color:#000000;position:absolute;top:2731.068;left:567.1293'>21,687.11</div>
<div style='font-size:10pt;font-family:Times;color:#000000;position:absolute;top:2731.068;left:666.3433'>100.00%</div>
<malformed html...>
```

I need to find the <div>Total</div> index then grab the data between the 1st and 3rd divs after that.

Comment: are you talking about strings?

Comment: It looks like you're pulling apart XML. If that's the case, why not use the XML libraries that will handle hundreds of edge cases that your manual string parsing won't.

Comment: It's a actually a string with a bunch of HTML I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, although this is some of the worse code I've ever written...

```
Dim sr As StreamReader

sr = New StreamReader("C:\test.html")

Dim xactHTML As String = sr.ReadToEnd

Dim left As Integer = xactHTML.IndexOf("Total</div>")
Dim chunk1 As String = xactHTML.Substring(left + 12)

Dim right As Integer = chunk1.IndexOf("<div style='position")
Dim chunk2 As String = chunk1.Substring(0, right - 1)

Dim xHTML As String = "<xml>" & chunk2 & "</xml>"

Dim e = XElement.Parse(xHTML)
Dim a = e.Elements().ToArray()

Dim damageAmmount As String = a(2).Value()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim e = XElement.Parse(str)
Dim a = e.XPathSelectElements("./blah").Elements().ToArray()

a(0).Value 'someData1
a(1).Value 'someData2
```

EDIT:
To parse html try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That would work great if it was XML data. I tried the above and my output HTML is coming from a piece of software called Xactimate and it doesn't make XHTLM friendly code so I'm getting a lot of errors like   "System.Xml.XmlException: '0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''."

Comment: For the "chunk" you specified you can use the above code just by adding a node around the div's

Comment: I'm now switching to that approach trying to extract that "chunk" of good html so I can use XPath...